# Deploy Hoverfly in cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am working in service layer mock with hoverfly.io and I would like to deploy it into Cloud Foundry, but so far, I am not able to deploy in Cloud Foundry. Any suggestion?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information here.  What have you tried?  What commands have you run?  What config are you using?  What is working?  What isn't working?  Are you getting specific error messages? etc...

Comment: I have the command to run my application: echo $PORT
./hoverfly -pp $PORT, and the logs said unknow port, when is trying to run the application

Comment: How can I know what port is known?

Comment: When your application is run `$PORT` should have the port on which your service should be listening.  In most cases, that port will be 8080.  It's not recommended, but if for some reason `$PORT` isn't working you could try hard coding port 8080.  Again, *not* recommended but might be a good troubleshooting step.

Comment: Thank you daniel I tried that yesterday, but it doesnt work too. I will expect for the solution of hoverfly

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'm running the hoverfly on CF in the standalone/webserver mode.

First, get the linux binaries of the hoverfly. Use the binary buildpack, so your manifest.yml may look like this:

```
---
applications:
  - name: my-mock-app
    buildpack: binary_buildpack
    memory: 64M
```

Add the hoverfly command that you want to execute in the Profile. Something like this:
web:

```
./hoverfly -webserver -pp $PORT -import path-to-your-json-file
```

You could use the command in your manifest.yml instead of Profile.

Instead of manifest you can execute like

```
 cf push hoverfly_stub -c './hoverfly -webserver -pp $PORT -import simulation.json' -b binary_buildpack
```

Push you app. Happy days :)
Works for me on PCF.

A couple of gotchas:

-Use hoverfly binary instead of hoverctl. The hoverctl will exit after you run it, so the CF will think your app crashed. The hoverfly runs in the foreground.

-Make sure you set hoverfly port to the one given by CF ($PORT variable)